# How to return null char reference

Tags: c++, null, char, operator-overloading

How do i return a null value? I created a local char set to null...but is there a different way to return a null lvalue?

```
char& String::operator[](int index) {
    char  s = NULL;
    if (index > length) {
        cout << "Incorect index.  Enter an index 0 through (String length -1)." <<endl;
        return s; // how do i return null value...this is local...
    }
    else {
    }
}
```

Comment: References are never supposed to be NULL. Use a pointer.

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong question.  I don't think you want to return a  reference to a null character.

Comment: First off, you don't set `char`s themselves to `NULL`. Second, you shouldn't return a reference to a local variable. In this particular case, you should throw an exception.

Comment: Why are you returning a reference to `char` instead of `char` without reference?  The `char` type is not large enough to warrant pass by reference (also, the value must be static).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intent is that the function should *always* return a valid reference (to a null character in this case), then you can use a static variable.

```
static char s;
s = 0;  // must do this every time in case the receiver modified the value last time
return s;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `s = '\0'`? `s = NULL` makes it look like `s` is a pointer, which it isn't.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen, either one will work, the `NULL` macro is defined as `0` anyway. But you're right that it conveys an incorrect assumption so I'll change it.

Answer (score 3):

You could return `'\0'`. That might get close to your intention.